# Can I create a Alexa Skill that can read my report available in CSV (or JSON) format?

Tags: bots, alexa-skills-kit

Can we create an Alexa Skill that could read out the data on my CSV (or JSON) file? I would like to create a voice-bot to read out my weekly report. I can have my report available in either CSV or JSON format.

It would be great if we aren't using any already built 3rd party apps. I would like to write it from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

As a short answer, yes. That should totally be possible. I currently have a skill that gets the response from a JSON file (it gets the required response, based on the intent of the user).

A CSV file should be fine too - you just need to parse it.

If your file is dynamic and changes often, you could potentially store the file in AWS S3, and fetch/read the content from there.

Once you have the string value for your speech response, from the JSON/CSV - just use that.

It doesn't say how you'd write your skill - but the [SDK for Node.js](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs) is pretty straight forward, and the documentation is good (with lots of examples too).